# Change background color of circle based on the numerical value NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to change the color of the background circle based on the {id} value. I'm using NextJs and Tailwind CSS for styling.

```
 <div className="rounded-full  bg-fixed h-8 w-8" style={{color: {id} === "1" ? "black-900" : "red-900"}} />
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: `{id}` should probably just be `id`...

Comment: Additionally to what @Naoe said, you should use `backgroundColor` instead of `color`, `color` is used define color for texts, not to define background color.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I found the right answer based on your comments, the issue also was that 1 should be without quotes.

```
 <div className={`rounded-full  bg-fixed h-8 w-8 ${ id === 2 ? 'bg-black-900' : 'bg-red-900'}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a ternary operator on the `className`:

```
<div
  className={`rounded-full  bg-fixed h-8 w-8 ${ id === '1' ? 'black-900' : 'red-900'}`}
/>;
```